# How to return class by value with prohibited copying?

Tags: c++

I have the following class and I just want to add a few simple function wrappers to return an instance of this class with some arguments/common initialization, just not to do it for each instantiation:

```
struct myClass
{
    myClass(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4 );

    myClass( myClassconst& ) = delete;
    myClass& operator=( myClass const& ) = delete;

    void doSomething();
};

// it is possible to simply return it
myClass createMyClass1234()
{
   return myClass( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
}
```

But is it possible to do this?
I actually don't want to copy it, just want to simplify this class creating with some initial actions.

```
// Error - copy ctor is deleted
myClass createMyClass1234andDoSomething()
{
    myClass ret( 1, 2, 3, 4 );

    ret.doSomething();

    return ret;
}
```

Can I move it somehow? I know, that I can return the pointer, but is it possible not to use dynamic memory?

Comment: `myClass&&`? That's the way it works for things like `std::thread` and `std::fstream` as well, to name just two examples. That's not "by value" though, but I guess that is not the relevant part in your question.

Comment: Yes it is possible with C++17.

Comment: *"Can I move it somehow?"* - You tell us. Is move semantics applicable to this class?

Comment: Yes, move semantics can be applicable for this class. How it will look like?

Comment: what c++ standard are you using ? Since C++17 your first version is ok https://godbolt.org/z/W7Kh9KMf5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add a [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor):

```
myClass( myClass &&) = default;
```

You probably also want [move assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment), but adding that one line will make your question code to work.

---

Depending on what your real class is, you may of course actually have to write some code, instead of just defaulting these. Look up [rule of 0/3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), it's one of the cornerstones of writing classes with modern C++. Since you are deleting the copy constructor, you should follow rule of 5, ideally just having `= default` for all of these.